# Table with separate boxes

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a table similar to this one. (I took it from my college notes) Where there are separated boxes with vertical lines that do not span the whole table. I've managed to replicate the horizontal lines and the multirow/multicolumn behaviour but I don't know how to create those separations between tables.

[image: Table]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! By use of `\hhline` package. For complete answer with code for your table you first need to show us what you try so far ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Zarko's comment I was able to replicate that using `\hhline` package.
Here you can find a pdf explaining how to use this package: [Link to hhline documentation](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/required/tools/hhline.pdf)

I created this simple table to see how the package works:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3} Fermiones (Spin 1/2) & & Carga eléctrica\\ \hhline{=-=}
    \multirow{6}{*}{Quarks} & u & \multirow{3}{*}{2/3}\\
    &c& \\
     &t& \\
    \cline{2-3}&d& \multirow{3}{*}{-1/3} \\
    &s& \\
    &b& \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Which gives the following table:

[image: Table]